# GNU assembly Inline: what do %1 and %0 mean?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, att

I am very new to GNU assembly inlining, I have read multiple write ups but still do not fully understand what is going on. From my understanding:

`movl %eax, %ebx\n\t` will move whatever is in `%eax` into `ebx`, but will not add the contents to each other

`addl %eax, %ebx\n\t` will add the contents of `%eax` with `ebx` and keep it at the right most register

`addl %1, %0\n\t` this is where i get confused, we are adding 1 and 0? why do we need to have the `%0` there?

Comment: In at&t syntax, the destination is the right side, so the "keep it at the left most register" is wrong. The %0 and %1 refer to substituted input/output operands listed in the constraints section. You might want to read the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Comment: @Jester Sorry was a typo, that is what I meant. that makes sense now, if I use %2, that will be 3rd input/output operands?

Comment: Yes. Also note you can use named operands in the form of `%[name]` to make the code more readable.

Comment: @Jester, thank you will definitely play around with that, thank you

Comment: You can always look at the compiler output to make sure things got substituted in for your %number placeholders the way you expected.  If using inline asm, make sure you tell the compiler when you clobber flags (condition-condes), with a "cc" entry in the clobber list.  You'll have an easier time learning asm if you write stand-alone functions in asm and call them from C.  (put a prototype in a `.h` or in your `main.c`, but only define the function in a `.s` file.).  gcc inline asm is harder to read/use than normal asm.  Use builtin functions whenever possible (e.g. for popcnt or SSE).

Comment: First recommendation: The 'authoritative' syntax is in the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html#Using-Assembly-Language-with-C). A better explanation and tutorial with real examples, pitfalls, and correct use can be found on the [lockless](http://locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/)  article. @PeterCordes' advice is excellent. Add some inline asm, compile with `-c -S`, and look at the assembly output. For simple inline (extended) asm, you can probably get away without yet knowing the ABI.

Answer (score 6):

The whole asm inline block looks like:

```
 asm [volatile] ( AssemblerTemplate
                      : OutputOperands
                      [ : InputOperands
                      [ : Clobbers ] ])
```

OR

```
 asm [volatile] ( AssemblerTemplate
                      : OutputOperands)
```

In the AssemblerTemplate is your assembly code, and in Output/InputOperands, you can pass variable between C and ASM.

Then in Asm, %0 refers to the first variable passed as OutputOperand or InputOperand, %1 to the second, etc.

Example:

```
 int32_t a = 10;
 int32_t b;
 asm volatile ("movl %1, %0" : "=r"(b) : "r"(a) : );
```

This asm code is equivalent to "b = a;"

A more detailed explanation is here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for links to more guides.